# How can I implement a class which extends an interface which accepts arguments of itself?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm using the Idiom from this Discussion [How can I make an interface instance method accept arguments of the same class only, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553621/how-can-i-make-an-interface-instance-method-accept-arguments-of-the-same-class-o):

```
interface ITree<SELF extends ITree<SELF>>{
    SELF getNode(int index);

    void setNode(int index, SELF node);
}
```

My question is, how can I implement the Tree which extends ITree in a right why? My current code looks like this:

```
public class B {
private ITree tree;
    public B (ITree tree){
        this.tree = tree;
    }
}
```

As expected it throws warnings that I should add a Type. I want to let the class which uses B decide which Type it should use. Or better I don't want to use generics at all for such a minor Problem.

Edit:

I found the solution after evaluating the answers. The devils detail was in this line:

```
<T extends ITree<T>>
```

Here is the full source code:

```
public class B<T extends ITree<T>> {
private T tree;
    public B (T tree){
        this.tree = tree;
    }
}
```

Comment: the `SELF extends ITree<SELF>` bound is useless. It should just be `SELF`.

Comment: With this, SELF could be anything.

Comment: Which is good since the bounds are not used in the code of that interface (which doesn't have code anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class B<T extends ITree> {
private T tree;
    public B (T tree){
        this.tree = tree;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still this doesn't change the fact that ITree needs a Type of the same Interface. Which still generates the same warnings. "ITree is a raw type. References to generic type ITree<SELF> should be parameterized."